# Residue of sin(1/z) and its poles

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having difficulty determining the residue of sin(1/z). Not even WolframAlpha computes this.

Is there any magic trick?

Comment: Yes. Substitution.

Answer (score 10):

Residue where? I presume you mean at $z=0$? Using the usual Taylor series for $\sin$, you obtain the Laurent expansion $$f(z) = \frac1z - \frac1{3!z^3} +\dots\,,$$ so the residue would be $1$.

Comment: I'd be curious what an unusual Taylor series for $\sin$ would be ;)

Comment: @DanielFischer: Troublemaker! Try the one centered at $z=\pi/3$ or, better yet, $z=31\pi/16$.